# Why a cow in the phrase "don't have a cow"?

Tags: expressions

Why a cow? Why not a sheep or goat in the phrase "my mom will have a cow if she finds out!"

Comment: [This has been asked before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116242/origin-of-to-have-a-cow) although there doesn't seem to be a real answer. There probably isn't a reason other than that cows are big and funny.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Origin of "to have a cow"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/116242/origin-of-to-have-a-cow)

Comment: The idiom is actually, "I don't have a cow what you're talking about".